# Generalized Logarithmic Integral - reference request

Tags: calculus, integration, reference-request, logarithms, closed-form

[This page](http://integralsandseries.prophpbb.com/topic227.html) at *I&S* forum defines the *Generalized Logarithmic Integral* as
$$L\left[ \begin{matrix} a,b,c \\ d,e,f \end{matrix};z\right] =\int_0^z \frac{\log^a x \log^b(1-x)\log^c(1+x)}{x^d (1-x)^e (1+x)^f} dx.$$
and gives several interesting closed forms for certain combinations of the parameters. I am looking for books, papers or other references where integrals of this form are studied and (at least some of) the closed forms given on that page are proved. Thanks!

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.12113

Comment: You might find info [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3763243) useful.

Answer (score 12):

Most of the integrals I have found in my version of Gradshteyn and Rhyzik have as reference [BI], which means

[BI] Bierens de Haan, D., Nouvelles tables d'integrales definies. Amsterdam, 1867.

which can be found here

https://archive.org/details/nouvetaintegral00haanrich

The PDF has 762 scanned pages, which makes it really slow for viewing.

There is also a project, initiated by Victor Hugo Moll,
to find proofs for the integrals in Gradshteyn and Rhyzik.

http://www.math.tulane.edu/~vhm/Table.html

there you can look for "logarithm" and click the green links (proofs) if available. I hope this helps.