# How can you approach $\int_0^{\pi/2} x\frac{\ln(\cos x)}{\sin x}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, fourier-series, polylogarithm

Here is a new challenging [problem](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=3200606550036121&set=a.222846247812181&type=3&theater):

Show that

$$I=\int_0^{\pi/2} x\frac{\ln(\cos x)}{\sin x}dx=2\ln(2)G-\frac{\pi}{8}\ln^2(2)-\frac{5\pi^3}{32}+4\Im\left\{\text{Li}_3\left(\frac{1+i}{2}\right)\right\}$$

**My attempt**:

With Weierstrass substitution we have

$$I=2\int_0^1\frac{\arctan x}{x}\ln\left(\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}\right)dx\overset{x\to \frac{1-x}{1+x}}{=}4\int_0^1\frac{\frac{\pi}{4}-\arctan x}{1-x^2}\ln\left(\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\right)dx$$

$$=\pi\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{1}{1-x^2}\ln\left(\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\right)dx}_{I_1}-4\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\arctan x}{1-x^2}\ln\left(\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\right)dx}_{I_2}$$

By setting $x\to \frac{1-x}{1+x}$ in the first integral we have

$$I_1=\frac12\int_0^1\frac{1}{x}\ln\left(\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}\right)dx$$

$$=\frac14\int_0^1\frac{1}{x}\ln\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)dx=\frac14\left[-\text{Li}_2(x)+\text{Li}_2(-x)\right]_0^1=-\frac38\zeta(2)$$

For the second integral, write $\frac{1}{1-x^2}=\frac{1}{2(1-x)}+\frac{1}{2(1+x)}$

$$I_2=\frac12\int_0^1\frac{\arctan x}{1-x}\ln\left(\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\right)dx+\frac12\int_0^1\frac{\arctan x}{1+x}\ln\left(\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\right)dx$$

The first integral is very similar to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3783058/evaluating-int-01-frac-arctan-x-ln-left-frac2x21x2-right1-xdx)

$$\int_0^1\frac{\arctan\left(x\right)}{1-x}\,
\ln\left(\frac{2x^2}{1+x^2}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x =
-\frac{\pi}{16}\ln^{2}\left(2\right) -
\frac{11}{192}\,\pi^{3} +
2\Im\left\{%
\text{Li}_{3}\left(\frac{1 + \mathrm{i}}{2}\right)\right\}$$

So we are left with only $\int_0^1\frac{\arctan x\ln(1+x^2)}{1+x}dx$ as $\int_0^1\frac{\arctan x\ln x}{1+x}dx$ is already nicely calculated by FDP [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1842492). Any idea?

I noticed that if we use $x\to\frac{1-x}{1+x}$ in $\int_0^1\frac{\arctan x\ln(1+x^2)}{1+x}dx$ we will have a nice symmerty but still some annoying integrals appear.

In $I$, I also tried the Fourier series of $\ln(\cos x)$ but I stopped at $\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{x\cos(2nx)}{\sin x}dx$. I would like to see different approaches if possible.

Thank you.

Comment: Bonus: $$\int_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} \frac{x \log ^2(\cos (x))}{\sin (x)} \, dx=-\frac{\pi ^2 C}{6}+2 C \log ^2(2)+16 \Im\left(\text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\right)\right)+8 \log (2) \Im\left(\text{Li}_3\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\right)\right)-\frac{\zeta \left(4,\frac{1}{4}\right)}{32}+\frac{\zeta \left(4,\frac{3}{4}\right)}{32}-\frac{1}{6} \pi  \log ^3(2)$$

Comment: Soon a bounty will be offered for a very elegant way to go.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Many ways to go are possible!**

A simple way would be to exploit the [known](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3050696) result,

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan(x)}{x}\log\left(\frac{1+x^2}{(1-x)^2}\right)=\frac{\pi^3}{16},\tag 1$$

since with the **Weierstrass subs** the main integral reduces to

$$\mathcal{I}=2\int_0^1\frac{\arctan(x)}{x}\log\left(\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}\right)\textrm{d}x$$
$$=-2 \int_0^1 \frac{ \arctan(x)}{x}\log \left(\frac{1+x^2}{(1-x)^2}\right) \textrm{d}x-2 \int_0^1 \frac{\arctan(x)\log (1-x)}{x} \textrm{d}x$$
$$+2 \int_0^1 \frac{\arctan(x)\log (1+x) }{x} \textrm{d}x$$
$$=2\log(2)G-\frac{\pi}{8}\log^2(2)-\frac{5}{32}\pi^3+4\Im\left\{\text{Li}_3\left(\frac{1+i}{2}\right)\right\},$$

where the last two integrals are calculated by **Ali Shather** in this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3261446.

**End of story**

Credit for this approach goes to **Cornel**.

**A first note:** Interestingly, different ways make the problem **very difficult**. It would be nice to have in place more ways to go.

**A second note:** The generalization of the **key integral** in $(1)$ may be found in the book, **(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series**, page $17$,

$$ \int_0^x \frac{\arctan(t)\log(1+t^2)}{t} \textrm{d}t-2 \int_0^1 \frac{\arctan(xt)\log (1-t)}{t}\textrm{d}t$$
$$=2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1} \frac{x^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)^3}, \ |x|\le1.$$

Comment: Perfect +1. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
I & \equiv \int_{0}^{\pi/2}x{\ln\pars{\cos\pars{x}}
\over \sin\pars{x}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
\bbox[5px,#ffd]{2\ln\pars{2}\,\mrm{G} - {\pi \over 8}\ln^{2}\pars{2} - {5\pi^{3} \over 32} + 4\,\Im\pars{\mrm{Li}_3\pars{1 + \ic \over 2}}}:\ {\Large ?}\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{align}

$\ds{\mrm{G}}$ is the [Catalan Constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant) and
$\ds{\mrm{Li}_{s}}$ is the [polylogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).

---

\begin{align}
I & \equiv \bbox[5px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}x{\ln\pars{\cos\pars{x}}
\over \sin\pars{x}}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] & =
\left. \Re\int_{x\ =\ 0}^{x\ =\ \pi/2}\bracks{-\ic\ln\pars{z}}{\ln\pars{\bracks{z + 1/z}/2}
\over \pars{z - 1/z}/\pars{2\ic}}\,{\dd z \over \ic z}\,\right\vert_{\ z\ =\ \exp\pars{\ic x}}
\\[5mm] & =
\left. -2\,\Im\int_{x\ =\ 0}^{x\ =\ \pi/2}\ln\pars{z}\,
\ln\pars{1 + z^{2} \over 2z}
\,{\dd z \over 1 - z^{2}}\,\right\vert_{\ z\ =\ \exp\pars{\ic x}}
\\[5mm] & =
2\,\Im\int_{1}^{0}\bracks{\ln\pars{y} + {\pi \over 2}\,\ic}\,
\bracks{\ln\pars{1 - y^{2} \over 2y} - {\pi \over 2}\,\ic}
\,{\ic\,\dd y \over 1 + y^{2}}
\\[5mm] & =
-2\int_{0}^{1}\bracks{\ln\pars{y}\ln\pars{1 - y^{2} \over 2y} + {\pi^{2} \over 4}}\,
\,{\dd y \over 1 + y^{2}}
\\[5mm] & =
-2\
\overbrace{\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{y}\ln\pars{1 - y} \over 1 + y^{2}}\,\dd y}^{\ds{I_{1}}}\ -\ 2\
\overbrace{\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{y}\ln\pars{1 + y} \over 1 + y^{2}}\,\dd y}^{\ds{I_{2}}}
\\[2mm] & + 2\ln\pars{2}\
\underbrace{\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{y} \over 1 + y^{2}}\,\dd y}
_{\ds{I_{3}}}\ +\ 2\
\underbrace{\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{y} \over 1 + y^{2}}\,\dd y}
_{\ds{I_{4}}}\ -\
\underbrace{{\pi^{2} \over 2}\int_{0}^{1}{\dd y \over 1 + y^{2}}}
_{\ds{\pi^{3} \over 8}}
\\ & =
-2I_{1} -2I_{2} + 2\ln\pars{2}\, I_{3} +2I_{4} - {\pi^{3} \over 8}
\label{2}\tag{2}
\end{align}
Those integrals are well known or/and *very -laboriously- doable*:
\begin{equation}
\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
\ds{I_{1}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{-\,{\pi \over 32}\,\ln^{2}\pars{2}} - {\pi^{3} \over 128} +
\Im\pars{\mrm{Li}_{3}\pars{1 + \ic \over 2}}
\\[2mm]
\ds{I_{2}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{\phantom{-}2\mrm{G}\ln\pars{2} +
{3\pi \over 32}\,\ln^{2}\pars{2}} + {11\pi^{3} \over 128} -
3\,\Im\pars{\mrm{Li}_{3}\pars{1 + \ic \over 2}}
\\[2mm]
\ds{I_{3}} & \ds{=} & \ds{-\,\mrm{G}}
\\[2mm]
\ds{I_{4}} & \ds{=} & \ds{\phantom{-}{\pi^{3} \over 16}}
\end{array}\right.\label{3}\tag{3}
\end{equation}
(\ref{2}) and (\ref{3}) lead to the coveted result (\ref{1}).

Comment: (+1) nice way to go.

Comment: nice work +1. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

$$ \int_0^1 \frac{\arctan x \ln(1+x^2)}{1+x} dx=\frac{\pi}{16}\ln^{2}\left(2\right) -
\frac{11}{192}\,\pi^{3} +
2\Im\left\{%
\text{Li}_{3}\left(\frac{1 + \mathrm{i}}{2}\right)\right\}+{G\ln2}$$
$$\int_0^1\frac{\arctan x\ln(\frac{2x}{1+x^2})}{1-x}dx=\frac{\pi^3}{192}-\dfrac{G\ln 2}{2}$$
$$\int_0^1\frac{\arctan x\ln(\frac{2x}{1+x^2})}{1+x}dx=\frac{\pi}{16}\ln^{2}\left(2\right) +
\frac{\pi^3}{24} -
2\Im\left\{%}
\text{Li}_{3}\left(\frac{1 + \mathrm{i}}{2}\right)\right\}-\dfrac{G\ln 2}{2}$$

Comment: With my due respect to your efforts, you always post only results as answers just like Cleo. What am I going to learn from it?

Comment: @Ali  Shather would like so much to do like you, but considering my age (80 years) I have a lot of difficulties with latex writing, so that to publish my results I have to resort to similar examples.Sorry

Comment: its totally fine and again I respect your work. My apology if my comment was rude.

Comment: I greatly appreciate your work, and I know the MSE community respects you.

Comment: Thank you sir for the kind words.