# Evaluate $\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\operatorname{Li}_3(-x)\ln(x-1)}{1+x^2}\text{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, indefinite-integrals, polylogarithm

Using $$
\operatorname{Li}_3(-x)
=-\frac{x}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^2t}{1+tx}
\text{d}t
$$
It might be
$$
-\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\ln^2t
\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{x\ln(x-1)}{(1+tx)(1+x^2)}\text{d}x\text{d}t
$$
Any suggestion is appreciated.

---

> An integral relation between three integrals
> $$
> \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(x)^2\ln(1+x)^2}{1+x^2} \text{d}x
> -2\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln^3(x)\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2} \text{d}x
> +4\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\operatorname{Li}_3(-x)\ln(x-1)}{1+x^2}\text{d}x
> = -\frac{3\pi}{64}\zeta(3)\ln2-\frac{21\pi^5}{256} +\frac{\pi^3}{64}\ln^22
> $$

Comment: Presumably, there is no nice answer in terms of ordinary polylogarithm alone. [Try running](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3763243) `MZIntegrate[PolyLog[3,-1/x]*Log[1/x-1]/(1+x^2), {x, 0, 1}]`

Comment: Also try playing around with this [approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3APolylogarithm%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Cint%20%20%5Cfrac%7BLi(x)%5Cln(x-1)%7D%7B1%2Bx%5E2%7D%5Ctext%7Bd%7Dx%24&p=1) which may give many hints.

Comment: @pisco What is the value of $$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\zeta(3)\operatorname{Li}_5(1-x)
\operatorname{Li}_7(1-x)\operatorname{Li}_9(1-x)
-\operatorname{Li}_3(1-x)\zeta(5)\zeta(7)\zeta(9)
}{x} \text{d}x$$?

Comment: @aaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbcccccc  The first integral has weight $22$, far too high for an explicit calculation. Presumably there is no nice answer.

Comment: @pisco How to express $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k^7\binom{2k}{k}}$?

Comment: @aaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbcccccc  This is a CMZV of level 5 and weight $7$, again no reason to expect a nice answer, there could be a slim chance for it to be expressible via polylogs though.

Comment: @pisco is this true?$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 
\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^3\binom{2n}{n}} 
\left(H_n^{(3)}+\frac{1}{5n^3} \right)
=\frac{2}{5}\zeta(3)^2$

Comment: @aaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbcccccc  This is still a conjecture, but I do have an idea on proving it.

Comment: @pisco Where do I find the value of $\zeta(3,\bar{1},\bar{1})$(all weight 5 MZVs)?

Comment: @aaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbcccccc  The command `MultiZeta[{3,1,1},{1,-1,-1}]` using my package.

Comment: @pisco Does your algorithm can convert iterated integrals into MZVs?

Comment: @aaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbcccccc  The process of converting iterated integrals into MZVs is used extensively in internal code of `MZIntegrate`.

Comment: @pisco Any explicit codes?

Comment: @aaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbcccccc  What are you working on (e.g. what level and weight of MZV)?

Comment: @pisco Like this one $$\int_{0}^{1} \text{d}x
\int_{x\ge t_2\ge t_1\ge0,x\ge u_3\ge u_2
\ge u_1\ge0}\frac{\text{d}t_1}{t_1} 
\frac{\text{d}t_2}{1-t_2} 
\frac{\text{d}u_1}{u_1} 
\frac{\text{d}u_2}{u_2}
\frac{\text{d}u_3}{1+u_3}.$$

Comment: @aaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbcccccc This is not a (homogenous) MZV, replace $dx$ by $dx/x$ or $dx/(1+x)$ to make it homogenous. If you really want to do this one, you need integration by parts to reduce it into a sum of homogenous MZV.