# Calculate $\int _0^1\frac{\arcsin ^2\left(x\right)\ln \left(x\right)\ln \left(1-x\right)}{x}\:\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, definite-integrals, harmonic-numbers, polylogarithm

this integral got posted on a mathematics group by a friend
$$I=\int _0^1\frac{\arcsin ^2\left(x\right)\ln \left(x\right)\ln \left(1-x\right)}{x}\:\mathrm{d}x$$
I tried seeing what I'd get from integrating by parts which got me
$$I=\frac{1}{2}\int _0^1\frac{\ln ^2\left(x\right)\arcsin ^2\left(x\right)}{1-x}\:\mathrm{d}x-\int _0^1\frac{\ln ^2\left(x\right)\arcsin \left(x\right)\ln \left(1-x\right)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\:\mathrm{d}x$$
and these seem quite hard to evaluate, I also tried expanding the integral in series but got nowhere.

I also tried using expressing $I$ the following way
$$I=\frac{1}{2}\int _0^1\frac{\arcsin ^2\left(x\right)\ln ^2\left(x\right)}{x}\:\mathrm{d}x+\int _0^1\frac{\arcsin ^2\left(x\right)\ln ^2\left(1-x\right)}{x}\:\mathrm{d}x$$
$$-\frac{1}{2}\int _0^1\frac{\arcsin ^2\left(x\right)\ln ^2\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)}{x}\:\mathrm{d}x$$
and the first $2$ integrals are probably doable but I can't think of a way to approach the last one.

Is it possible to evaluate $I$ or the third integral on the last equation in a fairly simple way?

Edit:
By Dilogarithm functional equations the following are also related
$$\int _0^1\frac{\arcsin ^2\left(x\right)\operatorname{Li}_2\left(x\right)}{x}\:\mathrm{d}x,\:\int _0^1\frac{\arcsin ^2\left(x\right)\operatorname{Li}_2\left(1-x\right)}{x}\:\mathrm{d}x$$
and therefore some very rough hamornic series are involved.

Comment: In your [last question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4670528), you asked a series without knowing its result, the result turns out to contain polylog constants. The result for this one is even more unfriendly.

Comment: Well I'm aware that this integral essentially is related to harmonic series of weight 5 structure so we'll be having a closed form in terms of classical linear elements like $\ln \left(2\right)\zeta \left(4\right)$, $\ln \left(2\right)\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$ ,$\operatorname{Li}_5\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$ though I'm suspicious it could contain other elements given it is not a linear one in nature.

Comment: It's indeed weight $5$, but it has **level 4**, what you said only applies for level 2. In this weight and level, the space (dimension 32) has 3 ugly constants which is (presumably) not a simple combination of polylog. One such ugly constant appear in the result.

Comment: Very interesting! perhaps some of them involve $\operatorname{Im} \text{Li}_5\left(\frac{1+i}{2}\right),\:\operatorname{Im} \text{Li}_5\left(1+i\right)$? you could post its closed form if you want, I wonder if it can be evaluated in a simple and tricky way.

Comment: One of the integrals in the post also contain $\operatorname{Re} \text{Li}_5\left(1+i\right)$ which I think can be expressed in terms of known constants.

Comment: $\operatorname{Im} \text{Li}_5\left(\frac{1+i}{2}\right),\:\operatorname{Im} \text{Li}_5\left(1+i\right)$ are related, and they're not those 3 ugly constants, neither is $\operatorname{Re} \text{Li}_5\left(1+i\right)$, it is of level 2, so again has a pretty formula in terms of $\text{Li}_5(1/2)$ etc.

Comment: If it can help, the integral is equal to:$$I=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}\int_0^\infty te^{-kt}\arcsin^2(e^{-t})dt$$

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int _0^1\frac{\arcsin ^2\left(x\right)\ln \left(x\right)\ln \left(1-x^{2}\right)}{x}\:\mathrm{d}x==\zeta_2\zeta_3 +\zeta_2\ln^3 2   -\frac{31}{32}\zeta_5-\frac{15}{8}\zeta_4\ln2$$

Comment: May you share how exactly you got this answer?

Comment: Note that this integral is different than the one proposed in the OP, your integral $I$ is:
$\displaystyle \int _0^1\frac{\arcsin ^2\left(x\right)\ln \left(x\right)\ln \left(1-x^2\right)}{x}\:dx=\frac{1}{8}\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{4^kH_k}{k^4\binom{2k}{k}}+\frac{1}{8}\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{4^kH_k^{\left(2\right)}}{k^3\binom{2k}{k}}-\frac{1}{8}\zeta \left(2\right)\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{4^k}{k^3\binom{2k}{k}}$, and you may find those series evaluated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3794846/how-to-compute-int-01-frac-textli-2x2-arcsin2xxdx-or-sum-n-1/4191353#4191353).