# Integral Representation of $\zeta^2(3)$ based on $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^ms\cdot\ln^n(1+s)}{1+s}ds$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Using Integer Relation Algorithms, I was able to arrive at the following :

$$12\zeta^2(3)=-40\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln s\ln^{4}(1+s)}{1+s}ds+40\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^{2}s\ln^{3}(1+s)}{1+s}ds-44\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^{3}s\ln^{2}(1+s)}{1+s}ds+23\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^{4}s\ln(1+s)}{1+s}ds$$

*Is it possible to simplify the Right Hand Side so that we have a nice Integral Representation for $\zeta^2(3)?$*

Maybe we can apply some Powerful Substitution.

The Coefficients do have Alternating Signs.

I thought to make a pattern appear by removing the powers of $2$ as :
$$5\cdot2^3,\ 10\cdot2^2,\ 22\cdot2^1,\ 23\cdot2^0$$

But this does not appear to be binomial.

Also, I do not expect it to be feasible considering the Coefficients do not exhibit any Binomial Pattern.

Comment: This is beautiful ! The first integral has a closed form. For the other ???

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Actually I had made a Conjecture based on numerical evaluations, using similar Integrals of the form $J(m, n)$ I was able to arrive at Integrals for $\zeta^2(3)\zeta(2)$, $\zeta^2(3)\zeta(4)$.
The one presented here is the simplest case.
Also I do not know the Closed Form of the Second Integral, but looking at the first one on Wolfram it seems to be quite complicated.

Comment: We have, for example $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^{2}s\ln^{3}1+s}{1+s}ds = \frac{1024}{23} \Re(\text{Li}_6(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}))+\frac{472}{23}\text{Li}_6\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+12 \text{Li}_4(\frac{1}{2}) \log ^2(2)+24 \text{Li}_5(\frac{1}{2}) \log (2)-\frac{3 \zeta (3)^2}{4}+\frac{7}{2} \zeta (3) \log ^3(2)+\frac{93}{8} \zeta (5) \log (2)-\frac{3221 \pi ^6}{60480}+\frac{341 \log ^6(2)}{1035}-\frac{101}{414} \pi ^2 \log ^4(2)-\frac{343 \pi ^4 \log ^2(2)}{16560}$$
this is in a sense the simplest possible (if only $\text{Li}_n$ is allowed). Similar results exist for other terms on RHS.

Comment: @pisco. Would you write an answer ? The problem is nice. Thanks in advance & cheers :-)

Comment: @pisco may I ask how did you derive that result?

Comment: @Black Emperor: You want a proof of your relation?

Comment: In low weight, $\displaystyle 3\zeta(5)=-16W_{1,3}+12W_{2,2}-8W_{3,1},W_{m,n}=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^m x\ln^n(1+x)}{1+x}dx$

Comment: @FDP Yes! A proof would be nice. Also the $\zeta(5)$ relation is nice, using system of equations I have extracted Zeta Values till Weight 10 from integrals of these form, though proving them would be rather hard.

Comment: This leads to the following conjecture. If $\displaystyle W_{m,n}=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^m x\ln^n x}{1+x}dx$ , $\displaystyle \zeta(n)^2=\sum_{i,j,i+j=2n-1}\underbrace{\lambda_{i,j}}_{\in\mathbb{Q}}W_{i,j}$

Comment: @FDP Nice! I had made the same conjecture but it actually broke! I wasn't able to extract $\zeta^2(5)$. I don't think it was due to numerical problems as I had no trouble extracting $\zeta(2)\zeta(3)\zeta(5)$ and $\zeta^2(3)\zeta(4)$

Comment: @Zima Probably very difficult to prove using elementary manipulations alone. But this is a consequence of systematic approach, see my answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4758677 or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3763243.

Comment: I don't see any try from you, and you still got upvotes, it's weird because many other people post their problems and they simply didn't know how to solve and want to be helped and got votes to close.

Comment: @OnTheWay I mean there are posts with $100$s of upvotes with just a problem statement so I don't know why you would single out this particular post. Also I think my question is being misinterpreted a bit, I wanted to convert the right side into a nice single integral but it seems impossible. Though thanks for the criticism, I will make try to make better posts from now on.

Comment: Another conjecture: If $\displaystyle W_{m,n}=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^m (1+x)\ln^n x}{1+x}dx$ and, $\displaystyle K_{n}=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x)\ln^n x}{1-x}dx$ then is $\displaystyle K_n=\sum_{i,j,i+j=n}\underbrace{\lambda_{i,j}}_{\in\mathbb{Q}}W_{i,j}$?? ($K_n$ is computable)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For $m,n$, positive integers,
\begin{align}W_{m,n}=\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{\ln^m(1-x)\ln^n x}{1-x}dx\end{align}

\begin{align}
K&=\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-x)\ln^4 x}{1-x}dx\\
J_1&=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^4 (1+x)\ln x}{1+x}dx\overset{u=\frac{x}{1+x}}=-W_{5,0}+W_{4,1}\\
J_2&=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3 (1+x)\ln^2 x}{1+x}dx\overset{u=\frac{x}{1+x}}=-W_{5,0}+2W_{4,1}-W_{3,2}\\
J_3&=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2 (1+x)\ln^3 x}{1+x}dx\overset{u=\frac{x}{1+x}}=-W_{5,0}+3W_{4,1}-3W_{3,2}+W_{2,3}\\
J_4&=\int_0^1\frac{\ln (1+x)\ln^4 x}{1+x}dx\overset{u=\frac{x}{1+x}}=-W_{5,0}+4W_{4,1}-6W_{3,2}+4W_{2,3}-W_{1,4}\\
S&=-40J_1+40J_2-44J_3+23J_4=\boxed{21W_{5,0}-46W_{3,2}+48W_{2,3}-23W_{1,4}}\\
\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{\ln^5\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)}{1-x}dx&=\boxed{-W_{5,0}+5W_{4,1}-10W_{3,2}+10W_{2,3}-5W_{1,4}+W_{0,5}}
\end{align}
Since,
\begin{align}W_{5,0}&=-\frac{\ln^6 2}{6}\\
W_{4,1}&\overset{\text{IBP}}=-\frac{1}{5}\Big[\ln^5(1-x)\ln x\Big]_0^{\frac{1}{2}}+\frac{1}{5}\underbrace{\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{\ln^5(1-x)}{x}dx}_{u=1-x}\\
&=-\frac{\ln^6 2}{5}-\frac{8\pi^6}{315}-\frac{W_{0,5}}{5}\\
W_{3,2}&\overset{\text{IBP}}=-\frac{1}{4}\Big[\ln^4(1-x)\ln^2 x\Big]_0^{\frac{1}{2}}+\frac{1}{2}\underbrace{\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{\ln^4(1-x)\ln x}{x}dx}_{u=1-x}\\
&=-\frac{\ln^6 2}{4}+\frac{1}{2}\underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-u)\ln^4 u}{1-u}du}_{=K}-\frac{1}{2}W_{1,4}\\
\end{align}
then,
\begin{align}S&=\boxed{8\ln^6 2-23K+48W_{2,3}}\\
\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{\ln^5\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)}{1-x}dx&=\boxed{10W_{2,3}+\frac{5\ln^6 2}{3}-5K-\frac{8\pi^6}{63}}\\
\frac{S}{48}-\frac{1}{10}\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{\ln^5\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)}{1-x}dx&=\frac{K}{48}+\frac{4\pi^6}{315}\\
S&=K+\frac{64\pi^6}{105}+\frac{24}{5}\underbrace{\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{\ln^5\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)}{1-x}dx}_{u=\frac{x}{1-x}}\\
&=\boxed{\frac{2\pi^6}{105}+K}
\end{align}

**Computation of $K$.**

\begin{align}K&\overset{\text{IBP}}=\left[\ln(1-x)\left(\int_0^x\frac{\ln^4 t}{1-t}dt-\int_0^1\frac{\ln^4 t}{1-t}dt\right)\right]_0^1+\\&\int_0^1\int_0^1\left(\frac{x\ln^4(tx)}{(1-x)(1-tx)}- \frac{\ln^4 t}{(1-x)(1-t)}\right)dtdx\\
&=\int_0^1\int_0^1\left(\frac{\ln^4 x+4\ln^3x\ln t+6\ln^2 x\ln^2 t+4\ln x\ln^3 t}{(1-x)(1-t)}-\frac{\ln^4(tx)}{(1-t)(1-tx)}\right)dtdx\\
&\overset{\text{Fubini}}=24\zeta(3)^2+\frac{4\pi^6}{45}+\int_0^1\int_0^1\left(\frac{\ln^4 x}{(1-x)(1-t)}-\frac{\ln^4(tx)}{(1-t)(1-tx)}\right)dtdx\\
&=24\zeta(3)^2+\frac{4\pi^6}{45}+\int_0^1\left(\frac{1}{1-t}\left(\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^4 x}{1-x}dx\right)-\frac{1}{t(1-t)}\left(\int_0^t\frac{\ln^4 u}{1-u}du\right)\right)dt\\
&=24\zeta(3)^2+\frac{4\pi^6}{45}+\int_0^1\left(\frac{1}{1-t}\left(\int_t^1 \frac{\ln^4 x}{1-x}dx\right)-\frac{1}{t}\left(\int_0^t\frac{\ln^4 u}{1-u}du\right)\right)dt\\
&\overset{\text{IBP}}=24\zeta(3)^2+\frac{4\pi^6}{45}-K+\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^5 t}{1-t}dt}_{=-\frac{8\pi^6}{63}}\\
K&=\boxed{12\zeta(3)^2-\frac{2\pi^6}{105}}
\end{align}

Therefore,
\begin{align}\boxed{S=12\zeta(3)^2}\end{align}

**Addendum**

**Bonus.**

\begin{align}\boxed{\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} \frac{\ln^2(1-x)\ln^3 x}{1-x}dx=-\frac{\ln^6 2}{6}-\frac{23\pi^6}{2520}+6\zeta(3)^2}\end{align}

Comment: Amazing Proof! I will wait for a while before accepting this as the answer.

Comment: Sorry no Digamma functions, no Beta function, no contour integrals, no harmonic sums, no series...my apologies!

Comment: Superb and so well presented !!